# How to determine if there is a user in mysql in BASH?

Tags: mysql, bash

How to determine if there is a user in mysql in BASH ?

```
if [ "$NAME_USER" == ???? ]; then
  echo "User exists in MySQL"
else
  echo "User no exists in MySQL"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read User; do
    if [[ "$NAME_USER" == "$User" ]]; then
        echo "$User exists in MySQL"
        break
    fi
done < <(mysql -B -N -e 'use mysql; SELECT `user` FROM `user`;')

if [[ "$NAME_USER" != "$User" ]]; then
    echo "$NAME_USER does not exists in MySQL"
fi
```

Comment: Using backticks in double quotes will cause the shell to execute "user". Also, you probably want `-B` and `-N` for mysql so the table header is not included in the output.

Comment: @jordanm thanks for correcting me on the quotes. I'm not using `mysql` very often in scripts, but when I do (usually I pipe the output to further process) table headers are excluded...

Comment: That probably depends on client version. From my experience, when used in a pipeline, it implies `-B`, but not `-N`.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose a script to make a mysql query and then parse the output.